# Gerador PHP de parsing

Tags: php

Amigos, sou estudante em php (online, pois na minha região não existem cursos em php). Se alguém puder me ajudar num projeto e me indicar quais as melhores ferramentas, agradeço. Também se já existe isso. Gostaria de criar um gerador php. O que tenho em mente? ter um Parsing PHP genérico sem dados (com variáveis) com propósito de coletar informações de determinados sites (As variáveis serão informadas posteriormente num formulário html) No formulário em html o usuário informaria a página de onde quer obter os dados e as variáveis pretendidas (em xpath, css, regex ou qualquer outro formato possível) e no formulário, e o resultado (depois de incluir os dados), clicando em salvar geraria um arquivo php com o código fonte e comandos necessários. Seria possível?

Comment: Amigo, EAD é muito melho do que presencial, vai por mim. Unica coisa que você perde no EAD é o contato com as pessoas, mas pra isso existe os fóruns. Não se sinta inferior só por que na sua cidade não tem algum curso presencial. Quem ganha é você.

Comment: Tudo é possível ! Mas a questão é ampla, então sugiro desmembrar sua questão em partes, colocando o que tem tentado... Considere fazer um [tour] e visitar a [help] para maiores detalhes do funcionamento do site, boa sorte.